# DATEDIFF does not give the correct number of days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to see the difference between 2 dates in days here is what I have

```
select DATEDIFF(DAY, BuildCMPLTDT, ValidCMPLTDT) AS DateDiff  from TrackerTest where TicketID='123456'
```

Where `2018-12-19 14:31:15.803` is `BuildCMPLTDT`, and `2019-01-22 15:40:35.533` is the date for `ValidCMPLTDT`

here is the results that I get: 43485. But, it actually should be something around 33 days!

Edited:
SO, I have a row that is like this:

```
BuildCMPLTDT               ValidCMPLTDT
2018-12-19 14:31:15.803    1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

and my second row is like this:

```
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000    2019-01-22 15:40:35.533
```

now, I want to have the datediff between the first `BuildCMPLTDT` which is  `2018-12-19 14:31:15.803` and the second  `ValidCMPLTDT` which is `2019-01-22 15:40:35.533`.

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct values of `BuildCMPLTDT` and `ValidCMPLTDT` ? Just running `select DATEDIFF(DAY, '2018-12-19 14:31:15.803', '2019-01-22 15:40:35.533')` gives `34`

Comment: @gtgaxiola, edited the post.

Comment: @nina_dev does only 2rows in your table?

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin, yes. because of the ticket number that I have used.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (DATEDIFF is a product specific function.)

Comment: @jarlh sql server

Comment: @nina_dev check answer please

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin your answer is deleted. The OP can't see it.

Comment: @SeanLange i already marked it undeleted

Comment: Thankfully, SQL Server doesn't attempt to implement [DWIM](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/D/DWIM.html) You have to provide it *explicit instructions* on how to pull the data together in a way that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dates you want to subtract are in different rows 
and both rows have the same `TicketID = '123456'`, right? 
The simplest way to do what you need is:

```
select DATEDIFF(
  DAY, 
  (select BuildCMPLTDT from TrackerTest where TicketID='123456' and ValidCMPLTDT = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'), 
  (select ValidCMPLTDT from TrackerTest where TicketID='123456' and BuildCMPLTDT = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')
) AS DateDiff
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b6b40abbca14a6e31c9624f57c6bedb6)

Comment: what if I donot have any data for validcmpltdt for the first row, and any data for buildcmpltdt for the second row. In other words, just focusing on build and val dates for these 2 rows. @forpas

Comment: If the id is the same is there any other column that provides ordering? If *you don't have any data for validcmpltdt for the first row, and any data for buildcmpltdt for the second row* is there something else to distinguish the 2 rows?

Answer (score 1):

Run this SQL and post your result,

```
select BuildCMPLTDT, isdate(BuildCMPLTDT),
       ValidCMPLTDT, isdate(ValidCMPLTDT),
       DATEDIFF(DAY, BuildCMPLTDT, ValidCMPLTDT) AS DateDiff
from TrackerTest 
where TicketID='123456'
```

**Update, since he needs datadiff() from two records**

```
select DATEDIFF(DAY, max(BuildCMPLTDT), max(ValidCMPLTDT)) AS DateDiff
from TrackerTest 
where TicketID='123456'
```

Comment: here is the results that I got from your script: BuildCMPLTDT (No column name) ValidCMPLTDT (No column name) DateDiff
2018-12-19 14:31:15.803 1 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 1 -43451
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 1 2019-01-22 15:40:35.533 1 43485

Comment: Two rows? You cannot let SQL do "pick the first column in the first row, subtract the second column in the second row".

Either forpas or my answer will work.

Answer (score 0):

use lead() analytic function

```
with cte as
(
select '2018-12-19 14:31:15.803' as BuildCMPLTDT,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' as ValidCMPLTDT
union all
select '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 ' as BuildCMPLTDT,'2019-01-22 15:40:35.533' as ValidCMPLTDT

) select DATEDIFF(day,BuildCMPLTDT,lead(ValidCMPLTDT) over(order by ValidCMPLTDT))  from cte
```

[Demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=83c4626679542202499a132d08664a9c)

Comment: Just curious here - you added twice your answer - here is the [link of your other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54677829/4092887).